# Can you check Big O notation by looking at a graph?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

Sorry for the simple question but I'm going through some algorithms homework and for true/false problems like...

n^n = O(2^n)

Is it always possible to just graph the two and see which one is bigger? In this case n^n is so I think the answer is false. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Look at the graph of 1000000n and n^2 for n up to some really large number, say n = 10,000. What looks bigger on the graph?

Comment: I see what you're saying, but even with that example n^2 will become bigger once n reaches 1000000.  If you multiply the "smaller" function by a constant c the bigger will always trump once the two equal one another. For n! = O(n^n) if you multiply n! by 100, n^n still grows larger just after n = 6.47....